# Cannot access XML node in as3

Tags: xml, actionscript-3

So I have my XML file loaded in as3 and I can see it is correctly loaded and it is the right file because I can trace it but when I try to trace a specific node, my output window remains empty. Here is my code:

```
var _textes:XML;
loader = new URLLoader();
requete = new URLRequest("texte_fr.xml");
loader.load(requete);
loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, finChargement);

function finChargement(pEvt:Event){
    _textes= new XML(pEvt.target.data);
}
```

If I trace _textes, I can see all my XML code but as soon as I try to trace a node in my XML file, I can't see anything. For exemple if I try to trace _textes.instructions, nothing comes up. What am I doing wrong?
Here is my XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<textes version="1" xmlns="http://xspf.org/ns/0/">
<instructions>
    Some text
</instructions>
<niveau1>
    <reussi>
        Some other text
    </reussi>
    <fail>
        Some other text
    </fail>
</niveau1>
<niveau2>
    <reussi>
        Some other text
    </reussi>
    <fail>
        Some other text
    </fail>
</niveau2>
<niveau3>
    <reussi>
        Some other text
    </reussi>
    <fail>
        Some other text
    </fail>
</niveau3>
<perdu>
    Some other text
</perdu>
<general>
    Some other text
</general>
<boutons>
    Some other text
</boutons>
</textes>
```

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** @fsbmain beat me to it with a proper solution, while I was editing my answer :) Here is my revised answer anyway...
You aren't getting the contents of that node because you are not referencing the node using the xml document's namespace.

This is how you should access your xml nodes:

```
function finChargement(pEvt:Event){
    _textes= new XML(pEvt.target.data);
    // The namespace in your xml document:
    var ns:Namespace = new Namespace("http://xspf.org/ns/0/");
    default xml namespace = ns;
    trace(_textes.instructions);
}
```

For more info see [this page](http://www.senocular.com/flash/tutorials/as3withflashcs3/?page=4%5d)

> Namespaces are used to separate or identify data. In XML they are used
>   to associate one or more nodes with a certain URI (Uniform Resource
>   Identifier). Elements with a namespace can have the same tag name as
>   other tags but still be separated from them because of their
>   association with a URI.

Here is an example:

Say you have this xml data:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<textes>
    <instructions  xmlns="http://xspf.org/ns/0/">
        Node 1
    </instructions>
    <instructions  xmlns="http://xspf.org/ns/1/">
        Node 2
    </instructions>
</textes>
```

If you access the "instructions" node using the namespace of the first node, you will get the first node's contents.

```
function finChargement(pEvt:Event){
    _textes= new XML(pEvt.target.data);
    var ns:Namespace = new Namespace("http://xspf.org/ns/0/");
    default xml namespace = ns;
    trace(_textes.instructions);
    // Will output "Node 1"
}
```

If you use the second node's namespace, you will get the second node's contents:

```
function finChargement(pEvt:Event){
    _textes= new XML(pEvt.target.data);
    var ns:Namespace = new Namespace("http://xspf.org/ns/1/");
    default xml namespace = ns;
    trace(_textes.instructions);
    // Will output "Node 2"
}
```

Comment: Please see my revised answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can set default namespace to empty in order to use e4x without specifying namespace  by this code:
        var xml:XML = Some text

```
    var ns:Namespace = xml.namespace("");
    default xml namespace = ns;
    trace(xml.instructions.toString()); //output "Some text"
```